# Ubuntu set -g is not available to change the behaviour of scrolling in tmux - getting postgres set

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scroll, tmux

Trying to get scrolling working in Ubuntu & tmux.  e.g. wheel scroll back through pages.

Most of the advice seems to be to do:

`set -g mode-mouse on`

However `set` has no `-g` option for me:

```
-bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

However I notice that the top of the 1st man page for set shows:

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.3 Documentation
```

Is the postgres 'set' "covering up" the regular `set` command that I want to use?

If so, how can I get around this and do the actual `set -g` that I want.

Comment: Is `set` a builtin? If so, I think you can do something with `buildin`.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean but I tried:  ` builtin set -g mode-mouse on
-bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is for the `~/.tmux.conf` file, or to be invoked to configure an already executing `tmux` by using:

```
tmux set -g mode-mouse on
```

Comment: It's a little strange kinda scrolling but this is the best (and in fact only) option that i've tried that worked.

Comment: The downside is that is screws up regular copying and pasting of other stuff while at the cli

Comment: Yeah, tmux and screen are hell for copy-pasting, but essential when dealing with flaky connections